# The range of values of a, so that all the roots of the equation are real and distinct, belong to

Tags: calculus, differential

The range of values of a, so that all the roots of the equation $$2x^3-3x^2-12x+a=0$$ are real and distinct, belong to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find values of $a$ for which function will have real roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809911/find-values-of-a-for-which-function-will-have-real-roots) (Found by [approach 0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%242%20x%5E%7B3%7D-3%20x%5E%7B2%7D-12%20x%2Ba%3D0%24%24&p=1))

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to consider when the roots are not distinct. For example, what happens when $a=-7$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=0$ has good number of real roots if $f_{min}<0$ ab\nd $f_{max}>0$.
the given function has min at $x=2$ and max at $x=-1$.So for real roots$ f(2)f(-1)<0$
This gives $(a+7)(a-20)<0 \Rightarrow -7 < a<20$ for three real distinctroots.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

hint: Write your equation in the form
$$a=-2x^3+3x^2+12x$$ and use for $$h(x)=-2x^3+3x^2+12x$$ calculus.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The function $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-12x$ has a local maximum $M$ and a local minimum $m$. The  equation $f(x)+a=0$ has three distinct real roots if and only if $-a\in (m,M)$.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates.